# Canceling WebClient download while waiting for download to complete

Tags: c#, cancellation, webclient

Looking for a more generally acceptable pattern of waiting for a `WebClient` to:

- Download a file (may take a couple of hundred milliseconds, or several minutes)
- Wait for the download to complete before performing any other work
- Periodically check another class's flag (bool) and cancel the download, if needed (cannot modify this class)

Constraints:

- Cannot use async/await unless it is something along the lines of `Task.Run(async () => await method())`
- When the `Download` method is called, it just needs behave like a normal method returning a string
- Can use any feature from .Net 4.5 and Roslyn compiler
- Makes no difference whether `WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync` or `DownloadFileAsync` is used; just need to have ability to cancel the download as-needed using a `WebClient`

Current implementation appears to be working, but doesn't seem quite correct. Is there a more generally acceptable alternative than using the `while` loop and `Thread.Sleep` to periodically check `otherObject.ShouldCancel` when using a `WebClient`?

```
private string Download(string url)
{
    // setup work
    string fileName = GenerateFileName();

    // download file
    using (var wc = new WebClient()) 
    {
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadCompleted

        Task task = wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, fileName);

        // Need to wait until either the download is completed
        // or download is canceled before doing any other work
        while (wc.IsBusy || task.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation) 
        {
            if (otherObject.ShouldCancel) 
            {
                wc.CancelAsync();
                break;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        void OnDownloadCompleted(object obj, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            if(args.Cancelled)
            {
                // misc work
                return;
            }

            // misc work (different than other work below)
        }
    }

    // Other work after downloading, regardless of cancellation.
    // Could include in OnDownloadCompleted as long as this
    // method blocked until all work was complete

    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: have you tried passing in a CancellationToken argument, and then use cancellationToken.Register(webClient.CancelAsync);?

Comment: I'd say while-sleep loop is fine with your requirements. Since `Download` should be synchronous - it has nothing to do while waiting for download to complete anyway, so why not to poll that flag meanwhile. Of course you can add some fancy stuff on top of all that, but that won't change much.

Comment: @KhaledElKholy - wouldn't the `otherObject.ShouldCancel` still need to be periodically polled to signal `cancellationToken.Cancel()`?

Comment: No, cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() would cause webClient.Cancel() to be invoked which you have registered as a callback which then causes the asynchronous task to throw WebException or TaskCanceledException. Also why don't you pass cancellationTokenSource instance to otherObject so that it could invoke cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() without having to check otherObject.ShouldCancel property periodically? do you have access to otherObject's type internal implementation?

Comment: @KhaledElKholy - I cannot modify anything in `otherObject` (see question, 3rd bullet point).

Comment: Why not subscribe to DownloadProgressChanged event and check for otherObject.ShouldCancel property there? it should be invoked frequently, so that you could have the chance to call wc.CancelAsync(); also you might want to call task.Wait() rather than looping and using Thread.Sleep(). If you use task.Wait() you would have to wrap it in a try catch block because it will throw AggregateException when wc.CancelAsync is called.

Comment: @KhaledElKholy - good idea; I had actually considered keying off the progress changed event, but ultimately decided against it, re: if the remote server starts to hang during the download, I wasn't sure if the progress change event would be raised which would lead to not being able to key off the `ShouldCancel` flag. I'm now leaning towards leaving as-is, unless I see some other compelling alternative that can be self-contained in this single method.

Answer (score 5):

I hope that this is helpful.
Basically your wrapper registers a callback using cancellationToken.Register(webClient.Cancel); once cancellationToken.Cancel() is invoked the asynchronous task should throw an exception which you might handle as follows:

```
public class Client
{
    public async Task<string> DownloadFileAsync(string url, string outputFileName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            cancellationToken.Register(webClient.CancelAsync);
            
            try
            {
                var task = webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, outputFileName);

                await task; // This line throws an exception when cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() is called.
            }
            catch (WebException ex) when (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is WebException exWeb && exWeb.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
            {
              throw new OperationCanceledException();
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
            }

            return outputFileName;
        }
    }
}
```

A simple way to try this example

```
    private async static void DownloadFile()
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var client = new Client();

        var task = client.DownloadFileAsync("url",
            "output.exe", cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        cancellationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        try
        {
            var result = await task;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Operation Canceled
        }
    }
```

In a more realistic scenario cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() would be called by an event raised due to user interaction or a callback.

**Update**

Another approach is to subscribe to DownloadProgressChanged event and check for otherObject.ShouldCancel when your callback is invoked.

Here's an example:

```
public class Client
{
    public string Download(string url)
    {
        // setup work
        string fileName = GenerateFileName();

        // download file
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += OnDownloadProgressChanged;
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += OnDownloadFileCompleted;

            DownloadResult downloadResult = DownloadResult.CompletedSuccessfuly;

            void OnDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (otherObject.ShouldCancel)
                {
                    ((WebClient)sender).CancelAsync();
                }
            }

            void OnDownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Cancelled)
                {
                    downloadResult = DownloadResult.Cancelled;
                    return;
                }

                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    downloadResult = DownloadResult.ErrorOccurred;
                    return;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                Task task = wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, fileName);
                task.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
            }

            switch (downloadResult)
            {
                case DownloadResult.CompletedSuccessfuly:

                    break;
                case DownloadResult.Cancelled:

                    break;
                case DownloadResult.ErrorOccurred:

                    break;
            }
        }

        // Other work after downloading, regardless of cancellation.
        // Could include in OnDownloadCompleted as long as this
        // method blocked until all work was complete

        return fileName;
    }
}

public enum DownloadResult
{
    CompletedSuccessfuly,
    Cancelled,
    ErrorOccurred
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I'm not entirely sure how this provides an alternative approach, though? 1)  `otherObject.ShouldCancel` is not being used to validate cancellation. 2) There is now an arbitrary 5 second timeout 3) Usage of `async/await` were specifically excluded as an option (see question).